# How to get a MD5 hash from a string in Golang?

Tags: cryptography, md5, go

This is how I started to get a `md5` hash from a `string`:

```
import "crypto/md5"

var original = "my string comes here"
var hash = md5.New(original)
```

But obviously this is not how it works. Can someone provide me a working sample for this?

Comment: The very best answer to this question is in the comments by @Alexei Danchenkov below. I've implemented them in a quick runnable example here: https://play.golang.org/p/e7v_erP7Gc

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Reference [Sum](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#Sum)，For me，following work well：

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("hello")
    fmt.Printf("%x", md5.Sum(data))
}
```

Answer (score 129):

```
import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func GetMD5Hash(text string) string {
   hash := md5.Sum([]byte(text))
   return hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])
}
```

Comment: Well done! I personally like that your simple wrapping works 'transparently' in the sense that so many other programming languages do the same thing...

Comment: what is the purpose of `hash[:]`? Thanks

Comment: @Madeo it means a slice which referencing the storage of (variable) `hash`, for the detail You can see here https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 43):

I found this solution to work well

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var str string = "hello world"

    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(str))
    fmt.Println(str)
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil)))
}
```

Answer (score 38):

From [crypto/md5 doc](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#New):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, "The fog is getting thicker!")
    fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

Comment: strings.Bytes doesn't exist anymore on -release, it's []byte(original)

Comment: Looks like `Hash.Sum()` needs a byte slice as first argument now. `h.Sum([]byte{})` will fix this example.

Comment: I have seen the documentation that this example is taken from but you haven't added anything to it, like an explanation for example. Why is io.WriteString() required? Why does h.Sum() require nil as an argument rather than taking the given string? A a GoNoob reading parroted examples is rather unedifying.

Comment: @IanLewis Writer `io.WriteString()` is unrelated to the subject. `fmt.Fprintf(h, "The fog is getting thicker!")` would produce the same result. Even clearer would be a one-liner `fmt.Printf("%x\n", md5.Sum([]byte("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")))`. `h.Sum(in)` called with any `in` would append the md5-hash of `h` to `in` - i.e. concatenate them (see the source, line 88: http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/md5/md5.go?s=2281:2313#L88).

Comment: Well. I would like to get the string instead of printing it to the console O.o...

Answer (score 19):

I use this to MD5 hash my strings:

```
import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func GetMD5Hash(text string) string {
    hasher := md5.New()
    hasher.Write([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(hasher.Sum(nil))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a function you could use to generate an MD5 hash:

```
// MD5 hashes using md5 algorithm
func MD5(text string) string {
    algorithm := md5.New()
    algorithm.Write([]byte(text))
    return hex.EncodeToString(algorithm.Sum(nil))
}
```

I put together a group of those utility hash functions here: https://github.com/shomali11/util

You will find `FNV32`, `FNV32a`, `FNV64`, `FNV65a`, `MD5`, `SHA1`, `SHA256` and `SHA512`

Comment: Well done, but your answer comes late... the same answer has already been provided three years before yours!

Answer (score 0):

just another answer

```
// MD5 hashes using md5 algorithm
func MD5(text string) string {
    data := []byte(text)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", md5.Sum(data))
}
```

Comment: That's litterally the content of the accepted answer.

Comment: Improved and simplified version :),

Comment: Could you explain the difference between your answer and https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942646/4834168 ?